# Can't deserialize to pojo class (Kotlin) (RestAssured)

Tags: kotlin, automation, automated-tests, rest-assured, autotest

**Hello! Here is the request to the server **

```
var stories: Story? =
given().log().all()
.contentType(ContentType.JSON)
.body(body)
.`when`().log().all()
.post(baseURI)
.then().log().all()
.extract().`as`(Story::class.java)

println (Story().title)
println (Story().id)
println (Story().items)
```

Here is POJO class

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class Data {
var stories: String? = null
}

class Story() {
var id = 0
var title: String? = null
var description: String? = null
var imageUrl: String? = null
var imageUrlEco: String? = null
var images: String? = null
var style: String? = null
var styleWeb: String? = null
var link: String? = null
var linkWeb: String? = null
var linkEco: String? = null
var buttonText: String? = null
var dateFrom: String? = null
var dateTo: String? = null
var hidden: String? = null
var isAuth: String? = null
var onboardingType: String? = null
var sortOrder = 0
var type: String? = null
var items: String? = null

}

class Item {
var id = 0
var title: String? = null
var description: String? = null
var detailedDescription: String? = null
var imageUrl: String? = null
var imageUrlWeb: String? = null
var style: String? = null
var styleWeb: String? = null
var sortOrder = 0
}
```

**And here is the response itself **

```
{
"data": {
"stories": \[
{
"id": 1234,
"title": "AnyText",
"description": "AnyText",
"imageUrl": "AnyText",
"imageUrlEco": AnyText,
"images": \[

                ],
                "style": "AnyText",
                "styleWeb": "AnyText",
                "link": AnyText,
                "linkWeb": AnyText,
                "linkEco": AnyText,
                "buttonText": "AnyText",
                "dateFrom": "2022-11-22T00:00:00Z",
                "dateTo": "2023-01-08T00:00:00Z",
                "hidden": AnyText,
                "isAuth": AnyText,
                "onboardingType": AnyText,
                "sortOrder": 1234,
                "type": "AnyText",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "id": 1234,
                        "title": "AnyText",
                        "description": "AnyText",
                        "detailedDescription": "AnyText",
                        "imageUrl": "AnyText",
                        "imageUrlWeb": "AnyText",
                        "style": "AnyText",
                        "styleWeb": "AnyText",
                        "sortOrder": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

}
```

So when I try this:

`println (Story().title)`
`println (Story().id)`
`println (Story().items)`

The result of running the program is:

`null`
`0`
`null`

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have not used RestAssured so I cannot comment on the syntax/correctness of that, but your error is incorrectly referencing the object you have deserialized from the GET request.

```
var stories: Story? =
```

this means assign the result to a variable named `stories`

Later you write

```
println (Story().title)
```

what this means it print the field `title` from a **brand new** `Story` object.  You should be doing this:

```
println (stories.title) 
println (stories.id) 
println (stories.items)
```

(`stories` should be named `story` if it represents one)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I changed the code to println(stories!!.title), But it still shows "null"

Comment: Then now the problem is that you have no content coming back form RestAssured.

Now I see the response. This does not properly match you data model at all. All sorts of inconsistencies... e.g. `Data` - this is not mentioned in your RestAssured call.  `"stories": \[` looks like stories will contain an array - what is that "\" doing there? and why in the `Data` class do you have `stories: String?` rather than `stories: List<Story`.  `images: String? ` in the data model, but data looks like an array. Images... 

Start with something a simpler, JSON like `{"foo":"bar"}` and work up from there.